# Как добавить теr к товарам через wp функцию?

Tags: php, wordpress

как можно добавить ко всем товарам сразу тег, я пробовал вот так присваивать, но не вышло

```
$posts = get_posts( array(
  'orderby'     => 'date',
  'order'       => 'DESC',
  'include'     => array(),
  'exclude'     => array(),
  'meta_key'    => '',
  'meta_value'  =>'',
  'post_type'   => 'product',
) );

foreach($posts as $tags) {

wp_set_object_terms($tags, 'до 2019', 'product_tag');}
```

Comment: wp_set_object_terms - первым аргументом принимает `ID записи, которую нужно связать с термином`, а вы всю запись отправляете

Comment: А как добавить именно post_type product?

Comment: [документацию](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_set_object_terms) читали? Там все это описано.  Надо передавать не $tags, а $tags->ID и тогда будет работать

Comment: Не получается, а в var_dump всего 5 товаров, хотя их на порядок больше

Comment: А про параметр `numberposts` знаете, читайте документацию или [wp-kamma](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_posts#numberposts-chislo)!

Answer (score 0):

Советую читать внимательней документацию и использывать класс `WP_Query`. 
Ниже пример кода для Вас, чтобы добавлять теги к товару или любому другому пост типу.

Внимение, нету проверок на успешное выполнение функции добавления тегов(`wp_set_object_terms()`), что хорошо бы делать, если, например, произойдет чтото не так.

```
// Установим параметры нужных нам постов
$load = [
    'post_type'      => 'product', // Пост тип продукт
    'posts_per_page' => - 1 // Количество, -1: получить все
];

$list = new WP_Query( $load );

// Если нашло посты
if ( $list->have_posts() ) {
    // Запустим цикл
    while ( $list->have_posts() ) {
        $list->the_post();
        // Установим теги
        // Изменить последний параметр на false, если надо разорвать старую связь записи с терминами и установить связь с новыми (указанными) терминами.
        wp_set_object_terms( $post->ID, 'Тег', 'product_tag', true );
    }
}
```